# Applet jar not being searched for files

Tags: java, applet

For example purposes, let's say I have a series of Locations on a website and the urls are of the form /location/#/ where # is the id of the location I want to view.  Since I'm using Django with Apache, all of my static content is in /media.  Each Location page is trying to load a Java applet that allows for file uploads.

```
<applet 
  codebase="/media/java/"
  code="com.elementit.JavaPowUpload.Manager"
  archive="JavaPowUpload.jar, commons-logging-1.1.jar, commons-httpclient-3.1-rc1.jar, commons-codec-1.3.jar"
  width="200"
  height="100"
  name="java-uploader"
  id="id-java-uploader"
  mayscript="true"
  alt="JavaPowUpload by www.element-it.com"></applet>
```

All of the listed jar files are in /media/java/ and are found by the web server.  The applet appears to load on the page without a problem but when looking at the network traffic during page load I see there are several errors.  Basically the applet seems to be looking for files that are within the jar, say com.elementit.JavaPowUpload.Messages_en.class, but is asking the web server for them, which amounts to requesting /media/java/com/elementit/JavaPowUpload/Messages_en.class, which of course does not exist.  Note that if I get rid of codebase and give the full path to each jar, I still have a similar problem where the request is then /location/#/com/elementit/JavaPowUpload/Messages_en.class.  How do I set things up so that the jar file is searched rather than the filesystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite taking this code from another page on a different server, it appears there is a slight error in the applet's code attribute.  Adding .class to the string fixed my problem, but I'm unsure why it works without it on the other host and page.

```
code="com.elementit.JavaPowUpload.Manager.class"
```

Comment: Just so people know, this appears to have been an oddity with JPU in particular, not with applets in general.  On updating to a newer version I had to remove the .class to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

See the [codebase_lookup](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/special_attributes.html#specialattributes) applet attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on that attribute, hadn't come across it before.  It appears that it is for when the search needs to expand outside the jar archives, in my situation the files *are* in the jars.